# Selenium Java Vk Keys Exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I perform below code I get an exception -

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.KeyEvent;


public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.olx.in/posting/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='add-file-1']/div/a   /span")).click();

    StringSelection selection  = new StringSelection("D:\\image.png");
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection, null);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(5000);     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);


}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    VK_CONTROL cannot be resolved or is not a field
    VK_V cannot be resolved or is not a field
    VK_V cannot be resolved or is not a field
    VK_CONTROL cannot be resolved or is not a field
    VK_ENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field
    VK_ENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field
When my tutor Performs the same operation he doesn't get any exception.
But when i do it on my pc i get an Exception.

Comment: When my tutor performs the same operation everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

not

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.KeyEvent;
```